# Install AMD proprietary drivers on Debian 9 for RX 470

Tags: debian, amd-graphics, amd

I tried to install the proprietary AMD drivers from the website, but it didn't work because they are only for SteamOS, Ubuntu and RHEL. The Debian wiki covers only older models of AMD GPUs. I searched everywhere but it only shows the Mesa drivers, which I don't want to use.

Specs:
AMD Radeon RX 470,
Debian 9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [proprietary driver](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux%20x86) stopped being updated a while ago and is no longer compatible with the X server used in Debian 9 (or in any other recent distribution — for example Ubuntu 16.04 and later aren’t supported either). For a Radeon RX 470, you should use the [amdgpu](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu) driver.

Comment: For a 64-bit i7, what would be the file with its corresponding architecture?

Comment: @CORONELBraian if you’re asking about installing the driver on a Debian system, you should run `apt install xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu`, and the correct file will be downloaded for you.

Comment: Yes, perfect. Now I know that for Debian Strectch with its 10 architectures, amd64 is for intel i7. Thank you