# Where to find driver for AMD/ATI Firepro V3800 card for Debian stretch or buster

Tags: debian, apt, amd-graphics

I want to install Debian Buster or as a second choice Debian Stretch with Cinnamon desktop on a HP Z200 with the manufacturer installed AMD/ATI Firepro V3800 card. So far attempts result in a notification 'Running in software rendering mode' with very poor quality and very slow graphics.  I believe I need to install a driver.  Web searches on how this could be done suggest loading packages such as firmware-linux-nonfree or firmware-amd-graphics  that are not available in any of the two releases.

In the answer for [Install AMD proprietary drivers on Debian 9 for RX 470](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/377937/install-amd-proprietary-drivers-on-debian-9-for-rx-470), which is similar to my issue, it seems that there might not be any package for recent AMD products?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It is about hardware installation, not software.

Comment: @Isaac  It is not a hardware question, it is about an operating system and drivers.  These are software

Comment: @ClintonWinant Have you tried using the `amdgpu` driver as th answer suggests, or is that the driver that's causing the rendering issues?

Comment: **You will need to add the non-free repositories**, before you can install those packages. AMD does not release hardware specs, so the free drivers are poor, there a are proprietary drivers, but these can get abandoned when AMD stop selling the hardware.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor  adding the non-free repos made everything work.  If you can request your comment as an answer, I can mark it as accepted.  Thanks

Comment: @eyoung100  Thanks for your comment.  The suggestion beneath yours allowed me to get a working system.  It turns out the missing link was firmware-amd-graphics, but the quality of the image is not very good.  Would the amdgpu package improve things?  Thanks

Comment: @Isaac If I wanted to aska question like "what is the best linux distribution to use with a AMD/ATI videa card", where would that be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You will need to add the non-free repositories**, before you can install those packages. AMD does not release hardware specs, so the free drivers are poor, there a are proprietary drivers, but these can get abandoned when AMD stop selling the hardware.